# how to pass the data from one Component to another component

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I have created two components. one is for the map and other one is for some inputs. I have two inputs to get the latitude and longitude. I am passing the longitude and latitude which i got from the user, to my other component using `longitude= {this.state.longitude} latitude = {this.state.latitude}`. If user haven't input the longitude and latitude or user clear the input it should show these coordinates `lat: 22.5726, lng: 88.3639`. how can i do it ? so far this is what i have done. when i pass the coordinates it doesn't show the place.what have i done wrong? And also i want to know how i can show the default coordinates when user clear the input? when i console.log `this.props.latitude` i get following error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'latitude' of undefined.` I think My data is not passing Properly to my map Component !if anyone knows how to fix this please tell!

this is my file structure.

```
MainFolder
 |
 |__ navigation.js
 |
 |__ right folder
 |     |
 |     |__form.js(this is where i have two inputs)
 |     |
 |     |__ MapContainerFolder
 |           |
 |           |__MapContainer.js
 |
 |
 |__ left folder
       |
       |__left.js
```

In my Form component i have below code

```
 <MapContainer
     longitude= {this.state.longitude}
     latitude = {this.state.latitude}
 />
```

in my navigation.js i have this

```
 <form/>
<left/>
```

this is my mapContainer.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {Map, InfoWindow, Marker, GoogleApiWrapper} from 'google-maps-react';

export class MapContainer extends Component {

  render() {
    const style = {
      width: '24%',
      height: '65%'
    }
    return (
      <Map 
      style={style} 
      google={this.props.google} 
      zoom={14}
      initialCenter={{
        lat: 22.5726,
        lng: 88.3639
      }}
      center={{
        lat:this.props.longitude,
        lng:this.props.latitude
      }}
      >

        <Marker onClick={this.onMarkerClick}
                name={'Current location'} />

        <InfoWindow onClose={this.onInfoWindowClose}>
            <div>

            </div>
        </InfoWindow>
      </Map>

    );
  }
}

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: ("my api key")
})(MapContainer)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `MapcContainer` class, you need to define your initail state based on the props you pass to this component from outside and set a default for them. Since I don't have a Google API key, I'm going to demonstrate your example in [Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/), but I'm sure you'll get the idea.

```js
const { Map: LeafletMap, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } = window.ReactLeaflet

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const lat = this.props.latitude || 51.505;
    const lng = this.props.longitude || -0.091;

    this.state = {
      center: [lat,lng],
      zoom: 13
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <LeafletMap center={this.state.center} zoom={this.state.zoom}>
          <TileLayer
            attribution='&amp;copy <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            url="https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          />
          <Marker position={this.state.center}>
            <Popup>Hello World!
            </Popup>
          </Marker>
        </Map>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");

const Wrapper = () => <App latitude={51.505} longitude={-0.091} />;
ReactDOM.render(<Wrapper />, rootElement);
```

Comment: i did what u said but i have still got that error. I think the latitude and longitude is not passing properly to MapContainer component . what i have i done wrong ?

Comment: is there any other way i can pass data to my mapContainer component?

Comment: Here's a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/2wnv7o1mlr